# How can I obtain a pointer to a point in a pcl::PointCloud

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` and I want to construct a graph over the individual points in the cloud.  I don't want to duplicate memory for the individual points in the cloud so would prefer to store pointers to those points in the graph.  How can I obtain a pointer to an individual point?  Can I just take the address of the `PointXYZ` returned by the iterator or is that a copy of the actual point?

Comment: You may have a look at my (reasonably documented) attempt at marrying PCL point clouds and boost graphs: https://github.com/taketwo/tcs/tree/master/include/graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be highly unlikely that an iterator for something like this would be making a copy of the data you're iterating over, and looking at http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_cloud_iterator.html, the iterator is constructed with a reference to the point cloud, and with operator*() returning a PointT&, so it looks like you could just store a pointer to this data.

Alternatively the iterator implementation appears to provide method to get the point index, which you could store instead.

to get the pointer from your iterator,

```
PointT* pointer_to_point = &(*iter);
```

If you are changing adding/removing points to the point cloud, you may also want to check that the pointers or indicies will still valid. I suspect they will be.